# inline-block floated element layout messes up on window resize

Tags: html, css-float, percentage, css

I have 2 50% divs with 2 buttons inside. each button needs to be aligned left and right. Issue is that if I apply floats the layout goes crazy on window resize. Without floats elements wrap nicely but both buttons ale aligned only to the left.

Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dominicm/pcYhL/15/

How can I align one button left and the other right while keeping the nice resize layouts?

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
<div id="www">
<input class="delAll" type="checkbox"><label class="delLabel" for="del-all">Delete</label>
<input class="pubAll" type="checkbox"><label class="pubLabel" for="pub-all">Publish</label>
<div>
<div id="d">
<input class="delete" type="submit" value="Delete Selected">
<input class="collapse" type="button" value="Collapse All">
</div>
<div id="p">
<input class="expand" name="expand" type="button" value="Expand All">
<input class="update" type="submit" value="Update Selected">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:7px;
    background-color:#666;
    text-align:center;
}
#www{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.delAll, .delLabel{

}
.pubAll, .pubLabel{

}

#d{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    min-width:140px;
    text-align:left;
}
#p{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    min-width:140px;
     text-align:right;
}

.delete{
    width:140px;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.update{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:140px;
}
.collapse{
    width:140px;
    float:right;
}
.expand{
    width:140px;
        float:left;
}
```

Comment: Responsive designs use percentages, not pixels.

Comment: I am using percent, some values I haven't updated yet for simplicity...

Comment: My point was if you use %s for the buttons, it'd be easier to turn into a responsive design. Not an answer, just a suggestion.

Comment: Well, I dont really want buttons to resize, I want them the same size and I dont need them to become much larger than they are.

Comment: That's what `max-width` is for. I reiterate, it's just a suggestion :)

Comment: Yeah I might use max-width but seems a bit of an overkill since buttons of this size will fit any device already, I woun't support devices with less than 140px resolution :)

Comment: Well back to the original question anyway, what would you actually like to happen when the window is relatively small and the buttons start stacking?

Comment: I simply want the buttons to stack without ugly transitions such as when center buttons are centered and other two are aligned left/right. I think this may be impossible with css alone, nothing worked so far (and it's been 2 days now)

Comment: It is possible (although I'm still not quite clear on what you want to happen, perhaps create some mockups at different widths?). You could try [css media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), at a certain width remove the floats and center the buttons instead.

Comment: What I want is: At high res: 4 buttons on 1 line. 2 buttons centered, other 2 aligned to left and right. At lower res: when there is no longer enough space for all 4 buttons on 1 line they should wrap so that I have 2 lines with 2 buttons aligned to left/right on both lines. When there is not enough space for even 2 buttons on 1 line then all buttons should be on their own line and all aligned to same side(ideally center). I am new to media queries, will look into it, but if you can post example that would be great.